# Why using window. to define a variable showing me some unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, variables

**I am using some functions to perform some task and want to access a variable out of the function for that I have used window to declare a variable**

```js
var countFirst;

var showList1 = data => {
  window.countFirst = data.length;
  //other statements
}

var showCompleteList = () => {
  //other statements
  showList1(data);
}

showCompleteList()
console.log(window.countFirst)
```

It is showing **undefined** in the console
Why it is showing that instead of its value which I have assigned in **showList1()** function.
If there is an error the how can I access this variable globally.
**Note: The variable is a number**

Comment: In which context is this script being executed?

Comment: I am working with nodejs and data is the response from the server. And I have used showCompletelist() function to add these content on my html page. I want to calculate the number of rows inside my database table so that I can use that number to draw some graph. Should I use this method or  there is something through which I can get the number

Comment: Well, Node.js doesn't even have `window`. You can use `global`, but it's kind of a bad practice. Why would you need to access global variables like that? Just use `countFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

> Amongst primitives "numbers" do not have "length" property only "strings" do. !!

```js
console.log((123).length); //prints "undefined"
console.log(("abc").length); //prints "3"

let x = 123; // a number
console.log(x.toString().length); // typecast to string and determine length

var countFirst;
var data = ["a", "b"];
var showList1 = data => {
  window.countFirst = data.length;
  //other statements
}

var showCompleteList = () => {
  //other statements
  showList1(data);
}

showCompleteList()
console.log("works as expected", window.countFirst)
```

Comment: data is an array here and countFirst is a variable of number type

Comment: I don't know why but it is giving me an undefined value

Comment: where are you trying to execute this ? chrome console ? - just copy paste it works

Comment: Yes, I am trying to print the result through the chrome console